# Can i get the path to a windows parition like D:/ using glob?

Tags: node.js, glob

I am using this to get to all the folders and subfolders:

```
var getDirectories = function (src, callback) {
Glob(directory + '/**/*', callback);
};
getDirectories(directory, function (err, res) {
 console.log(res);
)}
```

This works perfectly if `directory` is something like `D:/folder/`, but I can't get it to work with just `D:/`, is there a way I can find the path to `D:/`, does it have a path ? Is there another way to get this working ?

Comment: What is `Glob`? Which glob library are you using? If you are using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) maybe you can try passing options e.g. `Glob('/**/*', { cwd: directory },callback);` ?

Comment: @Domajno That worked